# How to integrate timepicker in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

How can I access a row in material-table (in editable mode) and integrate a timepicker from materialui?

```
<MaterialTable
    title=""
    columns={columns}
    data={state.data}
    editable={{
      onRowAdd: newData =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
            setState(prevState => {
              const data = [...prevState.data];
              data.push(newData);
              return { ...prevState, data };
            });
          }, 600);
        }),

      //onRowUpdate...

      //onRowDelete...

    }}
  />
```

[fields to change (yellow):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VrrW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

update to 1.69.0 to solve this issue.

---

Seems like the SandBox code from the accepted answer is not working anymore.
I created a new [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-with-date-time-wo3jt?file=/demo.js) just for others who are looking for a working code.

```
Note: Warning: Unknown event handler property `onBulkEditRowChanged`. It will be ignored.

is an issue with latest version (1.68.0) of material-table.
```

Added:
To fix the above issue, for now - 2020/08/16, we need to use **1.66.0**

*In 1.67.1 still, some warnings appeared.*

Comment: Are there any fixes for this problem? It looks like the sandbox you provided gives an error as well.

Comment: @matthewcoding0 you can check this comment: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2269#issuecomment-669939717

Answer (score 2):

You have to override both the render and the editCompoennt of the column.

I created a [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-gates-w55ye?file=/src/App.js) for you to show you how to do it.

The data should have a date or timeInMillis value named time. This will be passed to the render function of the column, which will parse it to be human readable:

```
render: ({ time }) => `${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}`
```

To edit, you have to override the editComponent with a TimePicker:

```
 editComponent: ({value, onChange}) => <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardTimePicker
      margin="normal"
      id="time-picker"
      label="Time picker"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      KeyboardButtonProps={{
        "aria-label": "change time"
      }}
    />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

This will let you edit/set a new time for that row and it will pass it back to the editable callback of the table, after the user clicks on save.

The callback will allow you to update the data.

Comment: Seems like the sandbox broke over time, i udpated the link